# Powershell or PowerCLI VMDK-to-DriveLetter

Tags: powershell, powercli

I've been fighting the 'problem' of matching Windows drive letters to VMDK's, and stumbled upon this almost by accident. This seems to work, but requires the entire 'sub' object from the get-vmguestdisk command be passed to the get-harddisk -vmguestdisk command. Does anyone know if there is a particular property of the get-vmguestdisk that makes this work? I'm just trying to make human logical sense that it really does find the correct harddisk given the guestdisk.

```
foreach($guestdisk in (get-vmguestdisk -VM MyVMServer)){
$vmdk=get-harddisk -vmguestdisk $guestdisk
$guestdisk.DiskPath+" "+$vmdk.filename
}
```

Comment: Just an edit. I apologize for omitting that one must have the PowerCLI modules installed, and a successful connect-viserver. And of course one or more VM guest names either manually or in some sort of loop.

Comment: I don't have an environment to test this on at the moment, but I think either the `ExtensionData` and/or the VM guest data provides the drive letter correlated with the disk number. Something like `(Get-VM $vmName).ExtensionData` or `(Get-VMGuest $vmName).Disks` or `(Get-VMGuest $vmName).ExtensionData`. Just spitballing. If you try those different variations of those commands I think you'll find it.

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/PowerCLI-script-to-lists-Windows-Drive-letter-and-VM-Disk-number/td-p/487403

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have seen that forum. The extensiondata for the objects has good info, but not that's convincing enough especially on servers with more than one disk that's the same size, or when the Windows partition doesn't fill the VMDK. I think I'll keep using the 'trust-but-verify' approach and spot check a couple of the 200-300 servers when I think there's a reason.

Comment: This relationship doesn't change often, but when another tech works on a server and doesn't say anything, a change goes unnoticed. This is used by backups on DB servers where they "only want the C: drive", and "don't touch my DB drives". Go figure.